# TextBox allows Text more than the MaxLength when Text is Assigned

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

TextBox's `MaxLength` was set to 5. It works fine that it does not allows to enter or paste the Text more than the `MaxLength`. But it allows when the Text is assigned from code.

Is it the behavior of TextBox? If it so, How to handle it in a generic way?

Comment: I would guess that the MaxLength is a user based limitation. In order to limit it through code you'll probably need to check the length of the field on keyup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it the behaviour of TextBox?

yes, it is behaviour of text box. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This property does not affect characters that are added
>   programmatically.

How to handle it in a generic way?

> You can control it progmatically by first checking the length of
>   string and then assigning. Like,

```
if(stringtoAssign.Length > yourTextBox.MaxLength )
{
    //or throw an exception, mesagebox. What ever you want
    yourTextBox.Text = stringToAssign.SubString(0,yourTextBox.MaxLength);
}
```